# What is the term for the short lines of a square bracket?

Tags: fonts, terminology

In a square-angled bracket, what is the name of the short horizontal lines at the top/bottom of the vertical line?  ex. [  ]

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how the glyph is constructed, ["arm"](http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/arm/) is probably your best bet. Some brackets are drawn in such a way that they might pass as serifs, though.

Comment: Nope. You'll find an "arm" on the cap Y, though. Bars are horizontal.

Comment: @Stan I'm not saying you're wrong, but I would like a source citation before I consider updating. My reference said that a [bar](http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/bar/) "differs from an arm and a cross stroke because each end connects to a stem or stroke" and that an arm "is the horizontal stroke on some characters that does not connect to a stroke or stem at one or both ends."

Comment: I would agree with you; but, then we'd both be wrong. My reference goes to anatomy. A Y and a T both have two "arms" while the K has one "arm" and a "tail." By your reference, an E has 3 "arms" (a physical freak). The terms developed to describe the look of the letters

Comment: How can a horizontal stroke on some letters not connect to a stroke or stem at one or both ends? Wouldn't that define a dash? Maybe consult with other correct references? They may draw a finer distinction between the terms, arm and bar. ... I may not be right; but, I'm never in doubt.

Comment: @Stan: I think it means "has at least one end which is not connected".  Thus, the horizontal line of an "H" would be a "bar" since *both* ends of it connect to other members.

Answer (score 2):

They are called bars. If horizontal bars cross the stroke, they are called crossbars.